# Split angular form into multiple parts

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I am making form builder using angular dynamic form, where i am loading the data for form from JSON as,

```
  jsonData: any = [
    {
      "elementType": "textbox",
      "class": "col-12 col-md-4 col-sm-12",
      "key": "first_name",
      "label": "First Name (Part 1 has first name and last name with title name of Person Name)",
      "type": "text",
      "value": "",
      "required": true,
      "minlength": 3,
      "maxlength": 20,
      "order": 1
    },
    {
      "elementType": "textbox",
      "class": "col-12 col-md-4 col-sm-12",
      "key": "last_name",
      "label": "Last Name",
      "type": "text",
      "value": "",
      "required": true,
      "order": 2
    },
    {
      "elementType": "textbox",
      "class": "col-12 col-md-4 col-sm-12",
      "key": "email",
      "label": "Email (Part 2 begins from here with title Personal details)",
      "type": "text",
      "value": "",
      "required": true,
      "minlength": 3,
      "maxlength": 20,
      "order": 3
    },
    {
      "elementType": "textbox",
      "class": "col-12 col-md-4 col-sm-12",
      "key": "mobile",
      "label": "Mobile Number",
      "type": "text",
      "value": "",
      "required": true,
      "order": 4
    },
    {
      "elementType": "textbox",
      "class": "col-12 col-md-4 col-sm-12",
      "key": "age",
      "label": "Age",
      "type": "text",
      "value": "",
      "required": true,
      "order": 4
    },
    {
      "elementType": "textbox",
      "class": "col-12 col-md-4 col-sm-12",
      "key": "Father Name",
      "label": "Father Name (Part 3 begins from here with Family details)",
      "type": "text",
      "value": "",
      "required": true,
      "minlength": 3,
      "maxlength": 20,
      "order": 5
    },
    {
      "elementType": "textbox",
      "class": "col-12 col-md-4 col-sm-12",
      "key": "mother_name",
      "label": "Mother Name",
      "type": "text",
      "value": "",
      "required": true,
      "order": 6
    }

  ];
```

Here everything works fine in generating the complete form..

But i would like to split up the form into **Person Name, Personal details, Family Details** with 2, 3, 2 input boxes respectively (the count may differ and its not static)..

**A clear working example** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x4a5b6-geesde

In this example you can see that the Json is generated as complete form and unable to make the title in between where i want..

How can i make a split up in the form and initiate title for respective part..

I would like to have order split up exactly like the below with title for each respectively.

**Person Name**

```
 -> First Name
 -> Last Name
```

**Personal Details**

```
 -> Email
 -> Mobile Number
 -> Age
```

**Family Details**

```
 -> Father Name
 -> Mother Name
```

Kindly go through the [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x4a5b6-geesde?file=src%2Fapp%2Fquestion.service.ts), which has the file with JSON and kindly help me to split up the form like the above order.

Answer (score 1):

I've once implemented something similar to what you are doing now. The idea is to create a special `elementType` for holding element groups.

The group config for person name, for example will look something like this:

```js
const grouped: any = {
  "elementType": "group",
  "label": "Person Name",
  "children":[
    {
      "elementType": "textbox",
      "class": "col-12 col-md-4 col-sm-12",
      "key": "first_name",
      "label": "First Name",
      "type": "text",
      "value": "",
      "required": true,
      "minlength": 3,
      "maxlength": 20,
      "order": 1
    },
    {
      "elementType": "textbox",
      "class": "col-12 col-md-4 col-sm-12",
      "key": "last_name",
      "label": "Last Name",
      "type": "text",
      "value": "",
      "required": true,
      "order": 2
    }
  ]
};
```

For the group you will need to create a separate component that loops through the children. You should also consider the case where there are groups inside groups. So, you need to make it recursive.

E.g.

```html
<div *ngFor="let question of questions" class="form-row">
    <ng-container *ngIf="!question.children">
                    <app-question [question]="question" [form]="form"></app-question>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngIf="question.elementType === "group" && question.children && question.children.length > 0">
                    <app-dynamic-group [questions]="question.children" [form]="form"></app-dynamic-group>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

Inside group container component you actually do something very similar to what you do in the dynamic form so, you could combine the functionality:

```html
<div *ngFor="let question of questions" class="form-row">
    <ng-container *ngIf="!question.children">
                    <app-question [question]="question" [form]="form"></app-question>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container *ngIf="question.elementType === "group" && question.children && question.children.length > 0">
                    <app-dynamic-group [questions]="question.children" [form]="form"></app-dynamic-group>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

Let me know if you need further explanation.

Here's a working version: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x4a5b6-gwkc2z?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdynamic-group.component.html

Comment: Ok. I will try to do it there.

Comment: KIndly fork my stackblitz and edit that is my json format so it will be easy for me to implement..

Comment: Give me 10 minutes

Comment: Ok, kinda done. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x4a5b6-gwkc2z?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdynamic-group.component.html
It generally works, so you can definitely get the idea. Probably requires a bit of refactoring though.

Comment: Was I supposed to create a complete solution? You can easily extend the functionality yourself. Moreover, it is not a perfectly working example. To be able to create groups of elements is not a 1 minute fix. You should understand this.

Comment: I gave you an example. It's not a complete working program. I already spent more than I expected. If you look at the code, you can adjust it without problems.

Comment: I extended your dynamic forms engine to be able to create grouped elements. This now works recursively. And based on the config you provide. Change the config and you'll see.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to Create sub form Component

Inside your top level form component place all you sub component

**app.component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <app-person></app-person>
  <app-family></app-family>
  <app-personal></app-personal>
  <button class="btn btn primary">Save</button>
</form>
```

Use ControlContainer

**ControlContainer**

> A base class for directives that contain multiple registered instances
>   of NgControl. Only used by the forms module.

ViewProviders to provide ControlContainer and use existing formGroupDiretive to get the parentForm then addformControl

**app-person.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, ControlContainer, FormGroupDirective } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-personal',
  templateUrl: './personal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./personal.component.css'],
  viewProviders: [{ provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: FormGroupDirective }]
})
export class PersonalComponent implements OnInit {
  personalForm;
  constructor(private parentForm: FormGroupDirective) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.personalForm = this.parentForm.form;
    this.personalForm.addControl('personal', new FormGroup({
      email: new FormControl(''),
      mobile: new FormControl(''),
      age: new FormControl('')
    }))
  }
}
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ewdzmp

Comment: Chellappan, Kindly help me build form only with JSON and angular dynamic form.. Please fork my stackblitz and create a new one with explanation regarding editing my JSON..

Comment: how would you differentiate the data person,family and personal?

Comment: For that only i am asking a help.. Because i was allowed to use only dynamic form and the data for that form needs to be from JSON.

Comment: how do you know which form field should go respective form ?

Comment: then how do you group the firstname and lastname as a one form and rest of the form?

Comment: Atleast help me technically how to make it with json and dynamic form alone.. Duplication of ```    <app-question [question]="question" [form]="form"></app-question>``` can be made not an issue..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183816/discussion-between-chellappan-and-undefined).

Comment: Hi ji, Can you help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53380789/how-to-combine-two-parts-of-single-form-in-angular

Comment: @undefined hi bro i wil help tomorrow