# Nested form array in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6, angular-reactive-forms

I am making angular application with reactive form, where i have made a nested form array which will get nested on button click.

A clean **working** example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-thhczx , it has static inputs and hence on click over `Add new template`, it will add a another nested part and for `Add new property`, it will generate another property array..

So you had got the above working example concept right??

I would like to have the same json but not with add button and with **dropdown**.

**Html of dropdown**:

```
<select multiple [(ngModel)]="selectItems" (change)="changeEvent($event)">
      <option *ngFor="let template of templates" [value]="template.key">{{template.value}}</option>
</select>

{{selectItems|json}}

<form [formGroup]="form">
    <div *ngFor="let item of array">
            {{item.value}} is the parent
      <div *ngFor="let child of item.templateChild">
        {{child.property_name}}
        <input type="text" [value]="child.property_name">
        </div>
        <br><br><br>
      </div>
      </form>
 <br><br><br>
{{form.value|json}}
```

**Templates array:** which gives value for dropdown

```
    templates = [
    {
      key: 1, value: "Template one",
      templateOneChild: [
        { property_name: "Property one" },
        { property_name: "Property two" }
      ]
    },
    {
      key: 2, value: "Template two",
      templateTwoChild: [
        { property_name: "Property three" },
        { property_name: "Property four" },
        { property_name: "Property five" }
      ]
    },
    {
      key: 3, value: "Template three",
      templateThreeChild: [
        { property_name: "Property six" },
        { property_name: "Property seven" }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Also made a **stackblitz** link for the above https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1sg5cv

Here if i select the option `template one` and `template two` (as the selectbox is multi select) from the dropdown then i am **expecting the output** as,

```
"template_details" : [
    { "template_name": "Template One",
      "template_data" : [{"property_one": "", "property_two":""}]
    },
    { "template_name": "Template Two",
      "template_data" : [{"property_three": "", "property_four":"", 
                            "property_five":""}]
    }
    ]
```

If you click over the two options of template one and two you can see that you will get `two` and `three` input boxes respectively...

I wish to generate the input boxes with property names automatically under each template on selection of dropdown values..

So in simple need to convert [dropdown demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1sg5cv) as like the [static inputs with add button](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-thhczx) with the same nested json structure.

I kindly request angular experts to help me in generation of input boxes based on property names for the selected template's..

I did my level best in it unable to get the solution please help me to form nested array json on based on selection of dropdown..

Comment: I wrote an answers. It's important that you understand the two "jobs" (make a formGroup and displayed). I leave a stackblitz but try make step by step the answer (at first your .html can be only a < pre>{{form?.value|json}}</ pre>) Cheers

Comment: @Eliseo, You were amazing thank you dear..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Undefined, you need two different jobs

1. Create a formGroup
2. Display inputs that manage the formGroup

the first part is the easer. Go step by step, if you select template one, you need some like

```
this.fb.group({
    template_name:"template one",
    template_data:this.fb.array([
          this.fb.group({
             property_one:'',
             property_two:''
          })
    ])
})
```

but you want to do the things dinamically, so, make a function that receive an object and return a FormGroup. As you only need the "value" of the template and the childs, your function can be like

```
createFormGroup(value:string,children:any[]):FormGroup
{
/*e.g. for template one, you send 
      value: "Template one",
      children: [
        { property_name: "Property one" },
        { property_name: "Property two" }
      ]
*/

     let controls:FormGroup[]=children.map(
          (x:any)=>this.fb.group({
              [x.property_name]:''
            })
     )
     return this.fb.group({
         template_name:value,
         template_data:this.fb.array(controls)
     })
}
```

So yet we can create a formGroup for the differents templates and join in a FormArray

```
changeEvent(e) {
    let arrayControls:FormGroup[] = [];
    //in this.selectItems we have, e.g. [1,3]
    for (let select of this.selectItems) {
      //search the template, select will be e.g. 1,3
      let template:any=this.templates.find(x=>x.key==select);
      switch (+select) {
        case 1:
          arrayControls.push(this.createFormGroup(template.value,template.templateOneChild));
          break;
        case 2:
          arrayControls.push(this.createFormGroup(template.value,template.templateTwoChild));
          break;
        case 3:
          arrayControls.push(this.createFormGroup(template.value,template.templateThreeChild));
          break;
       }
    }
    this.form=this.fb.group({
       template_details:this.fb.array(arrayControls);
    })
}
```

See that if all ours children of templates was under a property "children" (not templateOneChild for the first, templateTwoChild for the seconds...) our function becomes in

```
changeEvent(e) {
    let arrayControls:FormGroup[] = [];
    //in this.selectItems we have, e.g. [1,3]
    for (let select of this.selectItems) {
      //search the template, select will be e.g. 1,3
      let template:any=this.templates.find(x=>x.key==select);
      arrayControls.push(this.createFormGroup(template.value,template.children));
    }
    this.form=this.fb.group({
       template_details:this.array(arrayControls);
    })
}
```

Well you have the "form" created, now is time to show it. The form is like

```
<div *ngIf="form">
  <form [formGroup]="form">
    <div formArrayName="template_details">
      <div *ngFor="let item of details.controls;let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
        <input formControlName="template_name">

        <div formArrayName="template_data">
          <div *ngFor="let child of item.get('template_data').controls;let j=index" [formGroupName]="j">
         <input formControlName="??????????">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Yes, we have a problem, we don't know the "formControlName" of the inner formArray. One solution is have a variable "controlsName" that will be an array of array, so, if e.g. we choose 1 and 3 template our controlsName was like

```
controlsName=[
   ["property_one","property_two"],
   ["property_six",property_seven"]
]
```

Well, again make a function that return an array of strings with the names of the properties. it's a simply version of our createFormGroup, receive "children" and return an array of strings.

```
getControlNames(children:any[]):string[]
{
     let controlNames:string[]=children.map(x=>x.property_name);
     return controlNames;
}
```

Well, in changeEvent we call to this function after call to createFormGroup

```
changeEvent(e) {
    let arrayControls:FormGroup[] = [];
    let controlsName:string[] = []; //<--add this line
    for (let select of this.selectItems) {
      let template:any=this.templates.find(x=>x.key==select);
      switch (+select) {
        case 1:
          arrayControls.push(this.createFormGroup(template.value,template.templateOneChild));
           controlsName.push(this.getControlNames(template.templateOneChild)); //<--and this
          break;
        ... idem with case 2 and case 3...
      }
    }
    this.controlsName=controlsName; //<--give value to name first
    //then create the form
    this.form=this.fb.group({
       template_details:this.fb.array(arrayControls);
    })
```

After this, replace the < input formControlName="??????????" > by

```
<input [formControlName]="controlsName[i][j]">
```

See that we use [formControlName] (not formControlName) because is an evaluated expression.

See the stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qq6yoy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Eliseo, No more words to express thanks for you.. Even though you was late, you helped at right time.. Thanks a lot dear because of you i am learning complex things handling in angular.. I am really lucky to have you in this forum..

Comment: Eliseo, Is there any possibility for it?? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53607677/change-form-elements-using-angular-form

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your question.You want to dynamically add controls using json.

Reference link : https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form

Working example : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-srpk3w

Replace your files with the below code :

**app.component.html**

```
<select multiple [(ngModel)]="selectItems" (change)="changeEvent($event)">
      <option *ngFor="let template of templates" [value]="template.key">{{template.value}}</option>
</select>

{{selectItems|json}}
<div *ngIf="form">
<form [formGroup]="form"> 
    <div *ngFor="let item of array">
            {{item.value}} is the parent
      <div *ngFor="let child of item.templateChild; index as i">
        {{child.property_name}}
        <input type="text" formControlName="{{child.property_name.split(' ').join('_')}}"  [value]="child.property_name" >
        </div> 
        <br><br><br>
      </div>
      </form>
      </div>
 <br><br><br>
{{form.value|json}}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

    array: any[] = [];
    selectItems: any;
    form: FormGroup;

    templates = [
    {
      key: 1, value: "Template one",
      templateChild: [
        { property_name: "Property one" },
        { property_name: "Property two" }
      ]
    },
    {
      key: 2, value: "Template two",
      templateChild: [
        { property_name: "Property three" },
        { property_name: "Property four" },
        { property_name: "Property five" }
      ]
    },
    {
      key: 3, value: "Template three",
      templateChild: [
        { property_name: "Property six" },
        { property_name: "Property seven" }
      ]
    }
  ]


  changeEvent(e) {
    this.array = [];
    for (let select of this.selectItems) {
     this.array.push(this.templates[select-1])
     this.form=this.getFormValue(this.array);
      }     
  }
getFormValue(array){
  let group: any = {};
  array.forEach(r=>{
    r.templateChild.forEach((t,index)=>{
    group[t.property_name.replace(/ /g, "_")]= new FormControl(t.property_name);
    })
  })
return new FormGroup(group);;
}
}
```

Comment: Hope this helps

Comment: No the output is like expected output mentioned in question.. If i choose any parent template and their properties needs to list under the parent template.. In yours its getting appended every selection not separating parent and child..

Answer (score 0):

try this in ts

```
            import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
  this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    selectedItems: [[]],
    itemQuestions: this.formBuilder.array([])
  });
}itemQuestions: any[] = [
  { question: 'Question 1', options: ['Yes', 'No'] },
  { question: 'Question 2', options: ['Yes', 'No'] },
  { question: 'Question 3', options: ['Yes', 'No'] }
];

      generateItemQuestions(): FormGroup[] {
        const selectedItems = this.myForm.get('selectedItems').value;
        return selectedItems.map((item: string) => {
          return this.formBuilder.group({
            item: [item],
            answers: ['', Validators.required]
          });
        });
}

      onSelectionChange() {
        const itemQuestions = this.generateItemQuestions();
        this.myForm.setControl('itemQuestions',               
        this.formBuilder.array(itemQuestions));
        }

        onSubmit() {
          if (this.myForm.valid) {
            const formValue = this.myForm.value;
            console.log(formValue);
            // Perform necessary actions with the form data
          } else {
            // Form is invalid, display error messages or handle accordingly
          }
        }
```

in html

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Selected Items</ion-label>
    <ion-select formControlName="selectedItems" multiple="true">
      <ion-select-option value="Item 1">Item 1</ion-select-option>
      <ion-select-option value="Item 2">Item 2</ion-select-option>
      <!-- Add other options -->
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>
  
  <div formArrayName="itemQuestions">
    <div *ngFor="let questionGroup of myForm.get('itemQuestions').controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
      <div>
        {{ questionGroup.get('item').value }}
      </div>
      
      <div *ngFor="let question of itemQuestions">
        <div>{{ question.question }}</div>
        <ion-radio-group formControlName="answers">
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label>Yes</ion-label>
            <ion-radio value="Yes"></ion-radio>
          </ion-item>
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label>No</ion-label>
            <ion-radio value="No"></ion-radio>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-radio-group>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <ion-button type="submit">Submit</ion-button>
</form>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).