# How to change element to input or dropdown in angular form?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6, angular-reactive-forms

I am making angular 6 application, where i am using angular dynamic form and the values are coming from JSON..

**Simple JSON**:

```
  jsonData: any = [
    {
      "elementType": "dropdown",
      "key": 'project',
      "label": 'Choose option to display',
      "options": [
        { "key": 'inputbox', "value": 'Show Project Level as input box' },
        { "key": 'dropdown', "value": 'Show Project Level as dropdown' }
      ],
      "order": 1
    },
    {
      "elementType": "textbox",
      "class": "col-12 col-md-4 col-sm-12",
      "key": "project_level",
      "label": "Project Level as input box",
      "type": "text",
      "value": "",
      "order": 2
    },
    {
      "elementType": "dropdown",
      "key": 'project_level',
      "label": 'Choose Project Level as dropdown',
      "options": [
        { "key": 'low', "value": 'Low' },
        { "key": 'medium', "value": 'Medium' },
        { "key": 'high', "value": 'High' }
      ],
      "order": 2
    }
  ];
```

Requirement is going to be from this json only..

Take a look at **Clear working example** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x4a5b6-5ys5hf,

You can see at initial stage i am having both input box and dropdwon.. But i need to have text box alone at first if i choose the Show Project Level as dropdown from first dropdown, then the project_level key needs to change as select box and vice versa will happen..

**Order 1** has a dropdown in which i am having two options,

```
      "options": [
        { "key": 'inputbox', "value": 'Show Project Level as input box' },
        { "key": 'dropdown', "value": 'Show Project Level as dropdown' }
      ],
```

If we choose the **first** option which has value as **Show Project Level as input box**, whereas if we choose **second** option that has value **Show Project Level as dropdown**..

Based on the above selection, i need to switch the form element accordingly, say user chosen `Show Project Level as input box`, then i need to display the **input box**,

```
    {
      "elementType": "textbox",
      "class": "col-12 col-md-4 col-sm-12",
      "key": "project_level",
      "label": "Project Level as input box",
      "type": "text",
      "value": "",
      "order": 2
    },
```

Whereas if user chosen `Show Project Level as dropdown`, then i need to display the **dropdown**,

```
    {
      "elementType": "dropdown",
      "key": 'project_level',
      "label": 'Choose Project Level as dropdown',
      "options": [
        { "key": 'low', "value": 'Low' },
        { "key": 'medium', "value": 'Medium' },
        { "key": 'high', "value": 'High' }
      ],
      "order": 2
    }
```

So the **key** is going to be unique alone **project_level** but the form element alone needs to get changed based on the selection of either input box or selectbox..

Kindly help me to change the form element based on the selection on `order 1` dropdown..

Result is expected only using pure angular and typescript/javascript way without jquery..

Comment: Add an change event listener on the drop down .

Comment: @SumeshTG, It would be good if you post it as answer with working stackblitz because i am new in angular and dynamic form.. As of generation of dynamic form from JSON it did everything but switching the elements i am facing issues..

Comment: Is that shared stackblitz your example? or do you want same like that?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale, It is what i have tried.. You can see at initial stage i am having both input box and dropdwon.. But i need to have text box alone at first if i choose the ```Show Project Level as dropdown``` from first dropdown, then the ```project_level``` key needs to change as select box and vice versa will happen.. It was the example made by me and i need to switch the elements based on order 1 selection..

Comment: I am not sure how you are going to handle in case of a change request of UI! For ex: *If I want to add color for textbox background, then*

Comment: @PrashantPimpale, Here there is no need of involving in UI.. I already made a complete form using the JSON.. Only now i am having functionality level changes on for which alone this question is.. Please help me to achieve this functionality alone..

Comment: @undefined As I know, the way to do this by using `click` event but as I see you are accepting all attributes dynamically so you need the function name and click event handler dynamically to assign to the particular dropdown!

Comment: @PrashantPimpale, If you need reference then here is stackblitz for it https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x4a5b6-lngage?embed=1&file=src/app/dynamic-form.component.ts here i am displaying only selected dropdown option and others will be in hidden.. Whereas my question is concerned, it needs to be switch b/w input and dropdown for same key..

Comment: @PrashantPimpale, full reference stackblitz here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x4a5b6-lngage , Select the option from dropdown (choose option to display) then you will see the changes..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Undefined, or use two variables "project_level_textbox" and "project_level_dropdown", and make visible or not hte form or make that question.controlType depending the value of the formControl (some like when you're making visible or not a question)

Add a new property "controlTypeAlternative" with "type","field" and "value" and make the

```
[ngSwitch]="question.controlTypeAlternative?
    form.get(question.controlTypeAlternative.field).value==
 question.controlTypeAlternative.value?
        question.controlTypeAlternative.type:
        question.controlType:question.controlType"
```

If some complex the operator ? but main that If has the property controlTypeAlternative, check if the value of the form.control is equal. if not use "controlType"

Comment: Eliseo, Kindly please provide working example.. As because you helped me a lot, I hope you will make this solution little clear for me as like others with stackblitz..

Comment: Is it not possible to change with the same key as ```project_level```??

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x4a5b6-se5mt5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fquestion.service.ts